# Using React useEffect hook + Supabase realtime issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, supabase

I'm new player with `React`, `Next` and `Supabase` with realtime and I don't understand why I encountered an issue.

In the simplified example below, I'm displaying a user list with data from `Supabase`.
I subscribe to the users table for listening realtime changes in `useEffect` hook and return the unsubscribe function to clean up.

When I'm using `Paginator` to `setPage` and `fetchData` everything is OK, but when I receive updates from subscribe, `fetchData` is always executed with page in its initial state (page = 0), not current state.

The simplified example used:

```
export default function Index() {

    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0)

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const { data } = await supabaseClient
          .from<User>('users')
          .select('id, email')
          .range(page * 10, page * 10 + 10 - 1)

        setUsers(data)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()

        const usersSubscription = supabaseClient
          .from<User>('users')
          .on('*', fetchData)
          .subscribe()

        async function removeSubscription() {
          await supabaseClient.removeSubscription(usersSubscription)
        }
        return () => {
          removeSubscription()
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <UserList users={users}/>
        <Paginator page={page} .../>
    )
}
```

I think I'm violating the rules of hooks. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you updating the page state anywhere there.

You should `setPage` inside `fetchData` after you `setUsers`.

Comment: Yes, It's just a simplified example, even if page current state is 3, when executing fetchData(), page state equals 0, as initial state...